# How to watch git log and git status

Tags: git, terminal, watch

I would like to watch the output of the local `git status` and `git log` commands so that anytime a change is made to code in my local git repository the git status and git log commands are re-run and the new output is shown. Any ideas on how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `watch` command. For example `watch -n 5 git log` will rerun `git log` every five seconds.

Comment: You may want to run `git log -10` to view only the last commits, instead of the complete history

Comment: To preserve the color: `watch -c git -c color.ui=always log`

Comment: [Use `git log --decorate` to preserve the ref names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72196740/9157799) `(HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)`.